# ¿Código html antes del anchor text? ¿Tendrían problemas los motores de búsqueda?

Tags: html, seo

¿Es posible incluír código html antes del anchor text y si perjudicaría que los  pueda leer el crawler del buscador?

Es que necesito que el enlace tenga una anchura determinada, que no esté limitada por el tamaño del texto.

```
 <a href="/cine.php"><div class="3d-cine">
    <div class="text-3d-cine">CINE</div>
  </div>
 </a>
```

Como podéis observar, el anchor text está dentro de un div, y este a la vez está dentro de otro div, y fuera está el enlace que lleva al sitio.

Lo mismo es una duda tonta, pero nunca me he encontrado con un problema parecido, siempre he colocado el anchor text dentro del enlace y nunca de esta forma. ¿Tendrían problemas los motores de búsqueda?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

De acuerdo con las [especificaciones de HTML5](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element), una etiqueta `<a>` puede envolver a otras etiquetas de línea o de bloque siempre que no incluyan contenido interactivo (botones u otros enlaces):

> The a element may be wrapped around entire paragraphs, lists, tables,
>   and so forth, even entire sections, so long as there is no interactive
>   content within (e.g. buttons or other links).

De manera que el motor de búsqueda no debería tener problemas para encontrar el anchor text, dado que el marcado del texto es correcto.

De todas formas, y según lo que pretendas, tal vez puedas conseguir el efecto estético que necesitas sin tener que recurrir a `<div>`'s adicionales.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda. Excelente.

Comment: De nada, un placer!